# How to groupby aggregate min / max and plot grouped bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, bar-chart

I am trying to graph the functions of `min ()` and `max ()` in the same graph, I already could with the function of `max ()` but how can I join the two in the same graph and that it can be displayed correctly?
Example of my code and my output:

```
df.groupby('fecha_inicio')['capacidad_base_firme'].max().plot(kind='bar', legend = 'Reverse')
plt.xlabel('Tarifa de Base firme por Zona')
```

[image]

And my output of my dataframe:

```
               zona  capacidad_base_firme  ...  fecha_inicio   fecha_fin
0               Sur               1.52306  ...    2016-01-01  2016-03-31
1            Centro               2.84902  ...    2016-01-01  2016-03-31
2         Occidente               1.57302  ...    2016-01-01  2016-03-31
3             Golfo               3.06847  ...    2016-01-01  2016-03-31
4             Norte               4.34706  ...    2016-01-01  2016-03-31
..              ...                   ...  ...           ...         ...
67            Golfo               5.22776  ...    2017-10-01  2017-12-31
68            Norte               6.99284  ...    2017-10-01  2017-12-31
69            Istmo               7.25957  ...    2017-10-01  2017-12-31
70         Nacional               0.21971  ...    2017-10-01  2017-12-31
71  Nacional con AB              -0.72323  ...    2017-10-01  2017-12-31

[72 rows x 10 columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The correct way is to aggregate multiple metrics at the same time with [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), and then plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

  - There is no need to call `.groupby` for each metric. For very large datasets, this can be resource intensive.
  - There is also no need to create a figure and axes with a separate call to `matplotlib`, as this is taken care of by `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.
- **Tested in `python 3.9.7`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`**

```py
import seaborn as sns  # for data
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the test data
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

# display(df.head(3))
  species     island  bill_length_mm  bill_depth_mm  flipper_length_mm  body_mass_g     sex
0  Adelie  Torgersen            39.1           18.7              181.0       3750.0    Male
1  Adelie  Torgersen            39.5           17.4              186.0       3800.0  Female
2  Adelie  Torgersen            40.3           18.0              195.0       3250.0  Female

# aggregate metrics on a column
dfg = df.groupby('species').bill_length_mm.agg(['min', 'max'])

# display(dfg)
            min   max
species              
Adelie     32.1  46.0
Chinstrap  40.9  58.0
Gentoo     40.9  59.6

# plot the grouped bar
ax = dfg.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 6), title='Bill Length (mm)', xlabel='Species', ylabel='Length (mm)', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

- Use `stacked=True` for stacked bars

```py
ax = dfg.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 6), title='Bill Length (mm)', xlabel='Species', ylabel='Length (mm)', rot=0, stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, That helps me a lot learning Python!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Create a subplot to plot the data to

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

**Step 2**

Plot your DataFrame maximum and minimum to the specific axis

```
df.groupby('fecha_inicio')['capacidad_base_firme'].max().plot(ax = ax, kind='bar', legend = 'Reverse', label='Maximum')
df.groupby('fecha_inicio')['capacidad_base_firme'].min().plot(ax = ax, kind='bar', legend = 'Reverse', label='Minimum')
```

You may need to adjust the *zorder* to get the effect of a stacked bar plot.